# Cucumber How to Hover over an element?

Tags: selenium, hover, cucumber, capybara

I have an element styled with a css hover.

I tried using this

> page.execute_script(“$(‘#{selector}’).mouseover();”)

but does not work?

anyone else encountered this problem using a css hover? Thanks!

Comment: What does a cucumber have to do with anything here?!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

<s>I used .hover() and it worked. Thanks for the answers!</s>

I ended up having to add a class 'hover' to the element

```
element {
  &:hover, &.hover { //styles }
}
```

and trigger it in Cucumber by

```
page.execute_script(“$(‘#{selector}’).mouseover().addClass('hover');”)
```

Comment: Ya...what?  I'm running into this issue as well and I'm not sure what you meant by use `.hover()`.  I tried `page.find(".btn_thread_options").hover()` but I get `undefined method 'hover' for #<Capybara::Node::Element:0x0000012a23ed28>`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to correct this answer, I know it's a bit too late now but I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
 page.evaluate_script("$('#{element_name}').trigger('mouseover')")
```

Comment: Best to use "execute_script" if you don't care about the return value:  
  
    page.execute_script("$('#{element_name}').trigger('mouseover')")

Answer (score 0):

Here is step from my application

```
When /^I hover and click on "([^\"]*)"$/ do |selector|
  page.driver.browser.execute_script %Q{
    $("#{selector}").trigger("mouseenter").click();
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you coul call the function that is bound to that event